# ajax requesting sending in second click in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jsfiddle

i have the below knockout js code..

Design Code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="acmenu">
                        <ul id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: CategoryList">
                            <li data-bind="click$parent.categorySelected),attr:      {iddata.CategoryId},htmldata.CategoryName">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

```
self.categorySelected = function (selectedCategory, event) {
    $('#newproducttitle').hide();
    event.preventDefault();
    selectCategoryId = selectedCategory.CategoryId();
    var refurbishedUrl = "/services/ShopService.asmx/XGetRefurbishedproducts";
    $.ajax({
        url: refurbishedUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({ ItemID: itemid, categoryid: selectCategoryId, language: lang }),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

       /******Lines of code**********/

       }});
     }
```

This function is calling for every click but ajax requesting is sending for second click only. i need to send ajax request for first click, is there any solution for that....

here i am proving one drive link for js file  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=143242b617ba6be2!6684&authkey=!AAJQbpV8ZQ7fnGI&ithint=file%2ctxt

Comment: Can you provide some more information? I don't think there's enough here for anyone to help you. We need to know how categorySelected gets called etc. In your current code example, there's no evidence of any Knockout involvement at the moment other than the possible unwrapping of CategoryId. Try and replicate the problem in a JSFiddle. It will be much easier for someone to help you that way.

Comment: hello @yellowbrickcode click binding code is added in question..please check it..

Comment: click binding code should be like this:  <li data-bind="click:function(){$parent.categorySelected();},attr:{id: data.CategoryId},html:data.CategoryName">

Comment: None of your code would run. Please post code samples that are *at the very least* syntactically valid.

Comment: @Tomalak the design code is provided to show how can i call click event for my ajax request..

Comment: That's not the point. Your code is syntactically invalid, in addition to that it does not do what you want. Should the people who try to help you really have to fix your mismatched parentheses and other mistakes first because you can't be bothered to spend five minutes to post sample code that is consistent?

Comment: hello @Tomalak here is onedrive link for the file..   https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=143242b617ba6be2!6684&authkey=!AAJQbpV8ZQ7fnGI&ithint=file%2ctxt

Answer (score 1):

Though we don't have enough to work on still I think it is calling on first request as well (unless you have verified in developer tools etc.). The reason it seems to work on second click is that ajax call has not returned and on second click it appears to work.

Try this to disable button until ajax returns:

```
$.ajax({
        url: refurbishedUrl,
        data: ...,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend:function(){ $(event.target).prop('disabled', true);},        
 }).done(function(data){
           /*USE THIS INSTEAD OF success*/
 }).fail(function(data){
        /*USE THIS INSTEAD OF error*/
 }).always(function(){
        $(event.target).prop('disabled', false);
 });
```

Comment: have you tried using developer tools etc to confirm that there is no ajax call?

Comment: here is my js file please check it once...https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=143242b617ba6be2!6684&authkey=!AAJQbpV8ZQ7fnGI&ithint=file%2ctxt

Comment: I think has provided more detailed and better answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are using knockout against its design.

The viewmodel manages *data and state* - and nothing else. It is not supposed to contain any code that does HTML or DOM manipulation, **at all**.

In this case your data is a *list of category objects*. You want to inform the server when one of them becomes the *selected category*. Additionally you want to keep track of whether the viewmodel is *busy* talking with the server.

Therefore we need `categoryList`, `selectedCategory` and `busy` observables, as well as a subscription to changes in the selected category:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.categoryList = ko.observableArray([/* category objects ... */]);
    self.selectedCategory = ko.observable();
    self.busy = ko.observable(false);

    self.selectedCategory.subscribe(function (newCategory) {
        self.busy(true);
        API.post("XGetRefurbishedproducts", {
            ItemID: itemid,                          // wherever that comes from
            categoryid: newCategory.CategoryId(),
            language: lang                           // wherever that comes from
        }).done(function (data) {
            /******** Lines of code ********/
        }).always(function () {
            self.busy(false);
        });
    });
}
```

The view displays the category list, provides a way of changing the selected category, and reacts to whether the viewmodel is busy.

Therefore we need `foreach`, `text`, `click` and `disable` bindings:

```html
<div class="acmenu">
    <ul id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: categoryList">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: CategoryName"></span>
            <button data-bind="
                click: $parent.selectedCategory, 
                disable: $parent.busy
            ">Select</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that you can use an observable as a click handler.

---

Finally, to keep the viewmodel tidy, here's a helper that concentrates all Ajax handling in a central spot.

```
var API = {
    ajax: function (httpMethod, apiMethod, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: httpMethod,
            url: "/services/ShopService.asmx/" + apiMethod,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json"
        }).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
            console.error("Could not call " + method + ", error: " + error, data);
        });
    },
    get: function (apiMethod, data) {
        return this.ajax("get", apiMethod, data);
    },
    post: function (apiMethod, data) {
        return this.ajax("post", apiMethod, data);
    }
};
```